# Square of an infinitesimal equal to $0$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definition

The definition of a derivative: let $y=y(x)$. Then, $\dfrac{dy}{dx}= \dfrac{y(x+dx)-y(x)}{dx}$ . Now consider :
$$ cos(x)=\frac{sin(x+dx)-sin(x)}{dx}$$
$$cos(x)dx=sin(x)cos(dx) + cos(x)sin(dx)-sin(x)$$
$$cos(x)[(dx-sin(dx))]=sin(x)[(cos(dx)-1)]\tag{E01}$$

And:
$$-sin(x)=\dfrac{cos(x+dx)-cos(x)}{dx}$$
$$-sin(x)dx=cos(x)cos(dx) - sin(x)sin(dx)-cos(x)$$
$$cos(x)[(cos(dx)-1)]=sin(x)[(sin(dx)-(dx))] \tag{E02}$$
E01 and E02 together imply $cos(dx)=1$ and $sin(dx)=dx$. Both of which give the same result if we use the Maclaurin series for $cos$ and $sin$: that $(dx)^2$ and higher powers are **exactly zero**.

We can take up an easier example : consider $y(x)=\pi x^2$. By the formula,
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2\pi x=\dfrac{\pi(x+dx)^2-\pi(x)^2}{dx}$$
$$2\pi xdx=\pi[(x+dx)^2-(x)^2]=\pi[2xdx + (dx)^2]$$

Which implies $(dx)^2$=0.

**Is there a formal definition of "differentials" that allows us to *prove* that $(dx)^2=0$? Or do we accept it as an "axiom"?**

Comment: [There something along the lines of what you want to achieve.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonstandard_analysis)

Comment: @Raskolnikov but in those contexts (where the equation $\dfrac{dy}{dx}= \dfrac{y(x+dx)-y(x)}{dx}$ written by OP is considered to be valid), $dx^2 = 0$ is typically taken as part of the definition of $dx$

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1942006/81360) is relevant

Answer (score 1):

You are omitting that you must take the limit for $dx\to0$.

It is true that

$$\lim_{dx\to0}\frac{dx}{dx}=1$$

and

$$\lim_{dx\to0}\frac{dx^2}{dx}=0$$ by the theory of limits.

Then

$$\lim_{dx\to 0}\pi\frac{(x+dx)^2-x^2}{dx}=\pi\lim_{dx\to 0}\frac{2x\,dx}{dx}+\pi\lim_{dx\to 0}\frac{dx^2}{dx}=2x$$ is rigorous.

Comment: isnt a differential by definition tending to zero?

Comment: @satan29: in the old interpretation, yes, so you must account for that in your computations.