# Question about arclength (smooth infinitesimal analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, constructive-mathematics, infinitesimals

In the original version of this question, I asked about the value of $\sqrt{\epsilon^2}$ in smooth infinitesimal analysis. A helpful hint from Andreas Blass led me to check the definition of root, and I found that my original question was misguided since in SIA roots are only guaranteed for positive quantities, excluding $0$ and all infinitesimals.

My question was motivated by trying to understand the derivation of the formula for arclength; in particular the justification for the equation

$$\sqrt{\epsilon^2 + \epsilon f'(x)^2} = \epsilon(\sqrt{1 + f'(x)^2})$$

I know this question came up [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942006/why-is-it-considered-that-mathrm-d-x2-0), but it wasn't (so far as I can see) addressed head on the context of SIA. And it seems (in light of the above) that there are issues here. Don't we need to know that $\epsilon^2 + \epsilon f'(x)^2 \not=0$ to even know that root is defined? How else to we get that an infinitesimal increment in length is in fact $\epsilon(\sqrt{1 + f'(x)^2})$?

Comment: Is there a square-root operation in the rings used in SIA? I don't recall ever  having seen such an operation there. In fact, isn't part of the point of SIA that all functions are smooth?

Comment: Good question. I've been going off Bell's introductory book, which makes free use of square root (in particular in determining arc length, which is what led to this question). But I don't know if he's fudging details in the name of accessibility. I'll look into it!

Comment: Aha. So. You have square roots only for positive quantities in SIA. So there's no root 0, no root epsilon, and no root epsilon squared. That clears up the first part, but the thing about arc length is still a little opaque to me.

Comment: thanks Andreas, I will edit the question soon.

Comment: I understand the answer now. It's actually totally transparent from Bell's book, I was just completely barking up the wrong tree before because of my confusion about square roots. I could answer myself -- or should I just delete the question, given that a competent reader of Bell's book could easily get it?

Comment: As you figured out, the existence of square roots is guaranteed by the axioms only for positive numbers, and you can't prove $\neg \varepsilon \leq 0$, so the axiom won't give you a square root of $\varepsilon$ - or $\varepsilon^2 = 0$ for that matter.

But where does Bell assert that second equality? I have the second edition, and I could not find it in 3.3 Arc Length...

Comment: he doesn't assert the equality. I just assumed (partly 'cos I'm so used to SIA vindicating the intuitive arguments) that it would run like that. Actually what you do is consider the proportion of the extension of the curve to the hypotenuse of a right triangle with sides 1 and $f'(x)$ and work from there, presumably 'cos the root isn't availabe directly.

Comment: Splendid, you seem to have it figured out :). Don't delete the question, but consider writing up your answer as an answer! You can also accept your own answer, but you will have to wait 48 hours before doing so.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so I managed to resolve my confusion completely in the end. The main points are:

First, square root is only for $> 0$ quantities in SIA.

Second, the arc-length formula for $f$ can therefore not be derived in the intuitive way using the pythagorean theorem on an infinitesimal increase in $f$. What you'd like to do is to observe that the increase in the length along $f$ from $f(x)$ to $f(x + \epsilon)$ is $\epsilon \cdot \sqrt{1 + f'(x)}$ on the way to proving the standard formula. The natural approach is to consider the right triangle whose hypotenuse is the increment in $f$ and whose legs are $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon f'(x)$; the length of the increment would then be given by the pythagorean formula as $\sqrt{\epsilon^2 + \epsilon f'(x)^2}$. But we don't have this square root, since the term occurring in it is plainly $0$. This was what confused me, back in the days when I thought square root was defined everywhere.

How then is the result attained? The answer is there in the Bell, I just got really confused and didn't see it. $1 + f'(x)^2$ is always $>0$, so the root $\sqrt{1 + f'(x)^2}$ is always defined and represents the length of hypotenuse of the right triangle with legs 1 and $f'(x)$. If we divide the length of the infinitesimal increment in $f$ by this quantity we get $\epsilon$ (using some simple trig); one can then use this result to get the standard formula for arc-length (exactly as Bell does in his ["primer"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521887186) on p44).

Sad to see the intuitive argument not vindicated here. :'( :'(